# List the field contents of manually selected rows in a table, Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, list

I use ArcGis Desktop 10.8 and I try to create a tool with arcpy, but I got stuck on a part:

There are several shp files with several date column names, the column names vary depending on which shp file has which date column.

A summary table of all the files with all possible date names has been created.
[image]

From this table, the user manually selects a specific date row that is important to him, which he wants to delete from each shp file, if included.

Therefore, I would like to make a list of the names of the manually selected rows in the "F1" field, which is needed to delete the field. How can I list out only the manually selected names so that I have the correct input for the drop field in the iteration of Delete Field function later?

Answer (score 2):

If there is a selection on a layer, [da.SearchCursor](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) will only retrieve selected rows:

```
selected_rows = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("datum", "F1")]
```